# Identify book about a guy in his late teens/early twenties who goes to live with a family to tutor their teenage son

Tags: identification-request

I can't remember the name of a book about a guy in his late teens/early twenties who goes to live with a family to tutor their teenage son. Subsequently, the guy/tutor has an affair with the mother, while the teen son develops a crush on his tutor. I've only read the synopsis on Goodreads and the first chapter, so that's all I can describe.